# Where can I learn Android Classes as well as Theme Options?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android application.
Whenever, I am trying to develop the Android Application, I am tired of getting error messages either in console/ VDM regarding Theme Options, Versions, and etc.

Are there any tutorial websites (well explained) to study those topics?

For example, Appcompat v7, ActionBarActivity, Minimum SDK must be 16. etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Just use extends Activity in your class.Everything will work fine!

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorial websites but my personal favourite is androidhive.

Also, I've faced the same errors you have mentioned:

**ActionBarActivity**: Just replace **extends ActionBarActivity** with **extends Activity** and fix imports (Ctrl+Shift+O)

**AppCompat v7**: You can find this library at this location: your android sdk path\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. Just copy this library in your libs folder.

**Minimum SDK must be 16**: You must be using some libraries that require a minimum sdk of 16. Just change minimum-sdk property in AndroidManifest to 16 as shown below:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

You'll face many questions and many errors. Do not give up as every problem has a solution. Ask! Ask! Ask! ;)